# How to handle simple polymorphism with case classes?

Tags: scala, covariance

I have the following case classes:

```
object Fields {
  abstract class Base{
    def getString: String
  }
  case class A() extends Base{
    def getString = "A+++"
  }
  case class B() extends Base{
    def getString = "B++"
  }

  def fieldsToString(fields: List[Base]): String = {
    fields.tail.foldLeft(s"${fields.head.getString}") {(acc, f) =>
      acc + s",${f.getString}"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I tried to call this function in the following way:

```
 val fields = List(A, B, A)
 val result = Fields.fieldsToString(fields)
```

which gives me the following error:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : List[scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0[Product with Serializable 
with Fields.Base] with Serializable]
```

So I thought I needed to introduce covariance:

```
 def fieldsToString[T >: Base](fields: List[T]): String = {
        fields.tail.foldLeft(s"${fields.head.getString}") {(acc, f) =>
          acc + s",${f.getString}"
        }
      }
```

Which then gives me the following compile error:

```
do not conform to method fieldsToString's type parameter bounds [T <: Fields.Base]
```

What exactly is the problem, is this due to the case classes, do they behave differently then normal classes?

Answer (score 1):

Rightfold answer was close, what you have are not really functions but singleton types:

```
scala> case class A()
defined class A

scala> A
res0: A.type = A

scala> res0()
res1: A = A()
```

Quoting [the scala overview paper (on page 9, right column)](http://scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaOverview.pdf) by Odersky when talking about abstract members:

> Here, p.type is a singleton type, which represents just the object denoted by p. Singleton types by themselves are also useful for supporting chaining of method calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at the first error message, you see that you have created a list of functions. Call them:

```
val fields = List(A(), B(), A())
```

This is due to case classes implicitly having companion objects with `apply` methods.